# When search for right name display once when search for first character in name displays 5 times?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Seach in database only display firstname and lastname in Gridivew with linkbutton.

[image]

In the first Image(1) I Search only for the first Name, and get displayed firstname and last name.
In the second Image(2) I only search for the First character in the the and it displays it but I display it 5 times why? only want one time?

Here is my code

```
  private void GetEmployee()
    {
        var db = new knowitCVdbEntities();
        var employee = (from p in db.EMPLOYEES
                        where
                            p.firstname.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text) ||
                            p.lastname.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text) ||
                            p.position.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text)
                        select p).ToList();

        foreach (var vEmp in employee)
        {
            if (vEmp != null)
            {
                HiddenFieldID.Value = vEmp.employee_id.ToString();

                        if (Session["DataTableSearch"] != null)
                        {
                            _dt = (DataTable)Session["DataTableSearch"];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _dt.Columns.Add("Firstname");
                            _dt.Columns.Add("employeeId");

                        }
                        //_dt.Rows.Clear();
                        DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
                        dr["Firstname"] = vEmp.firstname+" "+vEmp.lastname;
                         dr["employeeId"] = vEmp.employee_id;

                        _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        Session["DataTableSearch"] = _dt;
                        GridViewDisplayName.DataSource = _dt;
                        GridViewDisplayName.DataBind();
                    }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Did you clear out your rows before displaying the new results?

Comment: no where should I clear them?

Answer (score 0):

As you go through this and run it, 
it will save the old searches as such,

so you will have to call _dt.clear at the start so that each time around you will only have one result, in theory :)

edit - Infact you actually have the clear in your code, just commented out, just in the wrong place :)

Answer (score 0):

Insert this right before your `foreach (var vEmp in employee)` line:

```
_dt.Clear();
```

So your code would be:

```
private void GetEmployee()
{
    var db = new knowitCVdbEntities();
    var employee = (from p in db.EMPLOYEES
                    where
                        p.firstname.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text) ||
                        p.lastname.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text) ||
                        p.position.Contains(TextBoxSearch.Text)
                    select p).ToList();

    _dt.Clear();

    foreach (var vEmp in employee)
    {
        if (vEmp != null)
        {
            HiddenFieldID.Value = vEmp.employee_id.ToString();

                    if (Session["DataTableSearch"] != null)
                    {
                        _dt = (DataTable)Session["DataTableSearch"];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _dt.Columns.Add("Firstname");
                        _dt.Columns.Add("employeeId");

                    }
                    //_dt.Rows.Clear();
                    DataRow dr = _dt.NewRow();
                    dr["Firstname"] = vEmp.firstname+" "+vEmp.lastname;
                     dr["employeeId"] = vEmp.employee_id;

                    _dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    Session["DataTableSearch"] = _dt;
                    GridViewDisplayName.DataSource = _dt;
                    GridViewDisplayName.DataBind();
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: should I not use _dt.Rows.Clear(); ?

Comment: Since you are using `_dt.Rows.Add()` you are adding new rows to your `DataTable`. Calling `_dt.Clear()` will remove your `DataRow`s right before you add new ones. Have you tried my solution yet?

Comment: Not if I write Anders it don't display anything but if I only write A , it displayS ?

Comment: So if you type only 'A', it displays 'Anders'. But if you type 'Anders', it doesnt display anything?

Comment: Everything works fine when I search when I don't use _Dt.Clear(); the only bad this is that when I seach for one character displays multiple

Comment: I u want and can I can post u all the codes that I use somewere, I use 3 functions that I call on from 3 table from sql.